# JQUERY, AJAX Request and then loop through the data

Tags: ajax, jquery, loops, each

Does anyone see anything wrong with the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/tags/ajax/post-tag/',
    data: { newtaginput : $('#tag-input').val(), customerid : $('#customerid').val()},
    success: function(data) {
        // After posting
        alert(data);
        arr = data.tagsinserted.split(',');
        alert(arr);
        //Loop through
        $.each(arr, function(n, val){
            alert(n + ' ' + val)
        }); 
    }
}, "json");
```

tagsinserted is what's being returned, here is the full response:

```
{"returnmessage":"The Ajax operation was successful.","tagsinserted":"b7,b4,dog,cat","returncode":"0"}
```

Thanks

Comment: my javascript interpreter eyes say - "its all good". no wait, what is "json" doing all alone by himself? shouldn't it be part of settings inside the first param. as in `{ .. , dataType: "json" });`

Answer (score 1):

Anurag is right in his comment  json needs to be `dataType:'json'`

also, unless specified, request is "GET" by default, your url suggests it is expecting post data, i.e. `type:'post'`